# What issues are seen in these C code fragments?

Tags: c

What is wrong with the following three C code fragments?

1. `struct abc *ptr;  printf("%d\n", ptr->field);`
   This one seems to have defined a structure pointer but is printing the value that the pointer holds.
2. `char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));`
   ptr is not defined first.??
3. `char *ptr = malloc(1000);  memset(&ptr, 0, 1000);`
   Is memset required to be used?

Comment: Please write a sensible title rather than trying to shoehorn three code fragments into the title where they cannot be formatted.  But really and truly, this is not a question that's suitable for Stack Overflow.  Please go and read the [About] and [Ask] pages (preferably after deleting this question, and doing that before it gets down-voted).  The list of problems is large — the middle fragment is possibly the least problematic, but still problematic.

Comment: Once you've got an answer, you can't change the question beyond recognition.  I rolled back your change that removed the `printf()` call, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Taken at face value, the problems include:

**Q1** `struct abc *ptr; printf("%d\n", ptr->field);`

1. The structure type is not complete so we have no way of knowing whether the structure has a member `field`.
2. The variable `ptr` is not initialized, so it cannot safely be dereferenced even if the type is known.
3. Because we don't know the type of `field`, we can't say whether the `printf()` format is OK or not.

**Q2** `char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));`

1. The space allocated for the 'string' is the size of a pointer, which is probably not the wanted size.
2. One common idiom is `SomeType *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));` to allocate enough space for a single object of type `SomeType`.  This is close but not quite there.
3. Adapting the idiom for an array of `N` objects (where `N` is a suitable integer value), you'd use `SomeType *ptr = malloc(N * sizeof(*ptr));` instead.

**Q3** `char *ptr = malloc(1000); memset(&ptr, 0, 1000);`

1. The allocation isn't checked.
2. The `memset()` should be passed the pointer value, not the address of the pointer:

   `memset(ptr, '\0', 1000);`

   but why not have the data zeroed by the memory allocation code using:

   `char *ptr = calloc(1000, sizeof(*ptr));`